# 'express' is not executable

Tags: node.js, express

This is quite basic. Many examples show terminal commands such as: 'express *name-of-directory-to-be-created*'. Yet on my system, though I've installed node.js (and command: node -v works, and npm -v works), command: express  fails with: *command not found* Further investigation shows that, on my macbook air, all incidences of express.js are not executable. I believe express was installed using *npm express* or *npm -g express*. Please, what is going on? Are the examples correct? ( There are several, all from various sources. ) How may I execute

> express *directory*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are talking about the `express-generator`, installable with `npm install -g express-generator`

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens on windows.
You need to install express globally and the location where npm modules get installed should be added to PATH(environment variable).

To install express globally type `npm install -g express`

Also it looks like you are trying to use express-generator.If yes you should install it similarly.
`npm install -g express-generator`

In windows by default npm modules are installed at "C:\Users\u_name\AppData\Roaming\npm"
Edit your PATH environment variable and append your npm path at the end.